# How to get file object (File API) of "upload" file input control in Upload Tab in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

I want to get the file object (as in File API) of image selected in file input control for validation from file input control named 'upload'. 
Please tell me how to do this.

```js
id: 'Upload',
     hidden: true,
     filebrowser: 'uploadButton',
     label: editor.lang.image.upload,
     elements: [{
                        tagName:'input',
      type: 'file',
      id: 'upload',
      label: editor.lang.image.btnUpload,
      style: 'height:50px',
      size: 38,
      onChange: function (event) {
          //alert(this.getValue()); //string value
          var sender = event.sender;
          var element = sender.getInputElement();
          console.log(element.files[0]); //this line gives the error
          
      }
      
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

File input element is created runtime and i m failed to get the file object from the runtime created input element.

After failure, finnally I get the value of this customized element and only applied extension validation (as given below) not the file size validation which was my important requirement:

```js
onChange: function (event) {

   var filename = this.getValue();
   var isValid = false;
   if (filename == '') {
          isValid = false;
   }else if (CheckFileNameOnChange(filename)) {
          isValid = true;
   } else {
         isValid = false;
         this.setValue('');
   }
return isValid;
}



function CheckFileNameOnChange(fileName) {
    
    var ext = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
    //alert(ext);
    if (ext == "gif" || ext == "GIF" || ext == "JPEG" || ext == "jpeg" || ext == "jpg" || ext == "JPG" || ext == "bmp" || ext == "png") {

        return true;

    }
    else {
        alert("Browse/Choose valid image.");
        return false;
    }
}
```